# detect gaps in integer sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

Intention: detect whether a numeric sequence contains gaps. No need to identify the missing elements, just flag (true / false) the sequence if it contains gaps.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(x INTEGER);
INSERT INTO foo(x) VALUES (1), (2), (4);
```

Below is my (apparently correctly functioning) query to detect gaps:

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT DISTINCT x FROM foo)
SELECT 
(  (SELECT COUNT(*)   FROM cte a 
                CROSS JOIN cte b
                         WHERE b.x=a.x-1)
  =(SELECT COUNT(*)-1 FROM cte))
OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte))
```

where the `OR` is needed for the edge case where the table is empty. The query's logic is based on the observation that in a contiguous sequence the number of links equals the number of elements minus 1.

Anything more idiomatic or performant (should I be worried by the CROSS JOIN in particularly long sequences?)

Comment: How do you feel about duplicate values?

Comment: @GordonLinoff they don't make any difference in my requirements, that's why I do a `select distinct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ((MAX(x)-MIN(x)+1 = COUNT(DISTINCT X)) OR 
           (COUNT(DISTINCT X) = 0)  )
           THEN 'TRUE'
           ELSE 'FALSE'
END   
FROM foo
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3e07d/1)</kbd>

Comment: reports 'FALSE' on an empty table, I guess one needs to also add an OR clause for the empty table edge case (if we accept that an empty table has no gaps)

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus I've added OR condition for an empty table. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following should detect whether or not there are gaps:

```
select (case when max(x) - min(x) + 1 = count(distinct x)
             then 'No Gaps'
             else 'Some Gaps'
        end)
from foo;
```

If there are no gaps or duplicates, then the number of *distinct* values of x is the max minus the min plus 1.

Comment: I believe that 'Some Gaps or Duplicates' should be 'Some Gaps' only.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach...

If you subtract your min value from the max value, and add 1, you should equal the count.

if count = (max-min)+1 then "no gaps!"

If you can express that in SQL, it should be very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'Has ' || count(*) - 1 || ' gaps.' AS gaps
FROM   foo f1
LEFT   JOIN foo f2 ON f2.id = f1.id + 1
WHERE  f2.id IS NULL;
```

The trick is to count rows, *where the next row is missing* - which only happens for the *last* row(s) if there are no gaps.

If there are *no rows*, you get `'Has -1 gaps.'`.
If there are no gaps, you get `'Has 0 gaps.'`.
Else you get `'Has n gaps.'` .. `n` being the exact number of gaps, no matter how big.
The count can be increased for duplicates, but `0` and `-1` are immune to dupes.